# Cancel ClickOnce update for a specific installation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce and have set it to automatically check for updates after the application starts. Some users don't want to be bothered with the update prompt because this application can be run from command line.

I wonder if it's possible to, since the update check is being made after the application starts, cancel this check from code.

I know one can handle the whole update from code, but this won't work for me because of some bug I run across long time ago related to the fact that my application have file/icon associations. I'm not 100% this was the bug but I'm pretty sure there was some bug that prevented me from handling the updates myself.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different behavior than the two predefined options in visual studio, you need to override the whole thing and uncheck the option to check for updates at all in visual studio.

It's really only a couple of function calls, though, so it shouldn't be so bad.

Whatever problem you were having with file associations shouldn't be related to this.  It's the same mechanism.

You could implement it such that it still checks for and applies updates on startup, but without any UI being presented to the user for it.  This would ensure that your application remains updated for all users, but would avoid the interruption that users object to when using it from the command line.

Comment: There's a bug where file assocations don't work right when doing updates programmatically with ClickOnce. This might be fixed with .NET 4.